# Are there any resources on the correct ordering of Apache .htaccess directives?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directive

I was tweaking my `.htaccess` file for the first time, and ran into the problem where my custom 404 page would not load because I placed the `Options -Indexes` directive after the `ErrorDocument 404` directive. Seeing as ordering directives willy-nilly can easily break the intended behavior, is there any online resource that details what the correct, or at least standard ordering of directives should be?

I couldn't find anything after a google search and a quick scan of the Apache docs.

Comment: In this case, the ordering shouldn't matter (and doesn't seem to, on my test server). Are you sure that was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad - the actual problem was that I was using a comment on the same line as a directive.